concatenating windowed VCF files, but quickly?
I am calling variants from WGS for a genetically diverse species which, with my sample size, produces a (bgzipped) VCF of around 500G. I am using a nextflow pipeline to chunk up the genome, call variants in windows and then concatenate them back together.
The variant calling itself takes about a week with freebayes, with nextflow running 100 concurrent processes and a total of about 8000 windows. The problem is that the concatenation step is taking nearly as long.
I'm doing the concatenation like this (nextflow script block below):
R1=\\\$(head -n 1 ${regionlist})
    zcat "\\\${R1}.vcf.gz" | awk '{if (\\\$0 ~ /^#/) print \\\$0; else exit}' >header.txt
    HL=\\\$(cat header.txt | wc -l)
    START=\\\$(expr \\\$HL + 1)

    # cat header file, cat all vcfs, starting at # header lines + 1, sort, uniq, bgzip
    (
        cat header.txt
        for file in \\\$(cat ${regionlist}); do 
           bgzip -d -c "\\\${file}.vcf.gz" | tail -n +\\\${START}; 
        done
    ) | \
    vcfstreamsort | \
    vcfuniq | \
    bgzip >out.vcf.gz

The sorting step is meant to deal with overlap at window edges on the scale of 10kb, not sorting the entire file (which I imagine would make this problem far, far worse). if unzipping and rezipping was the bottleneck though, and parallel can be made to output in input order, then I could use parallel here.
I'm just wondering if anyone has tips for making this faster, or even ideas about how to figure out what the bottleneck is. It seems crazy that just pasting the VCF files back together takes this long.
As a side note, I've run this pipeline before and had no problems, but the pipeline errored out on this species because the vcfstreamsort | vcfuniq steps did not actually work, and tabix threw an error because there were duplicated, out of order variants (at window edges). I'm trying it again with an updated version of vcflib to see if it solves the problem, hence the whining about how long it's taking.
edit:
Hardware: I am working on an institutional HPC. The data are on a network attached file system. I don't think we have storage that is local to each node. I'm not knowledgeable about HPC infrastructure, but our network is described as "10/40/100 GbE".
Filtering: these VCFs are already pre-filtered lightly, so all the terrible junk is gone. There are just tons of variants.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
